# Why do we have a negative current in cyclic voltammetry curves?

Tags: electrochemistry, cyclic-voltammetry

Why do we have a negative current in cyclic voltammetry curves?
here are my thoughts. We have two conventions in reporting data of CV curves: the IUPAC convention and the US convention. In the IUPAC convention, the potential scan direction is from lower potential to higher and the US convention is reversed of the IUPAC convention (from higher potential to lower potential). So I think it's all about the direction of current in an electrochemical cell. because anodic current will be positive in the IUPAC convention and negative in the US convention. Therefore, maybe It does not relate to cathodic or anodic current. Can anyone explain more? what is the concept of the negative current?

Comment: In cyclic voltammetry, the applied potential cyclically alternates, going more positive, then more negative, with respect to a reference potential. The resulting currents likewise alternate between positive and negative.

Comment: Ok. That's right. I wanna ask one more question. can we have the CV that all cathodic and anodic currents of the CV are positive?

Comment: It is possible to add a constant current, either positive or negative, thereby shifting the CV up or down on the current axis. This could be deliberate, to accommodate a current-input ADC that requires unipolar input currents. Or it could be inadvertent, as a consequence of a leakage current or the like. I think this is what you mean, but correct me if I got it wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but I have another question. In electrochemical sensors (like glucose sensors) when we are adding the analyte to the electrolyte, the Cv current will shift to a positive value. (both cathodic and anodic current are positive). what do you think about it?why do we have this?

Comment: I don’t know the answer to that. Per se, adding glucose would not cause a shift of the whole CV. Unless someone here has a helpful suggestion, I think you will have a little investigation to do. This is how research typically goes.

Comment: Yeah, sure Ed. Thanks for your help. Yes, I am searching for that. but I am a little confused. By adding different concentrations of glucose the whole CV shifts up. For faster scan rate we have the same result that for faster scan rate the whole current increase and both anodic and cathodic current are positive value.